# Where is the file containing deployment.security settings in Server JRE 8?

Tags: java, server, configuration-files

Does the Oracle Java Server JRE have a **deployment.security** file? Can I safely make one and put it in the C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ folder?

My task is to configure the JRE according to a security checklist. Six items on this checklist refer to settings in "the 'deployment.properties' file for Java." I cannot find this file in the Java folder or anywhere on my system disk.

I have a Tomcat 8 web service running on Windows 2008 R2. I installed the Server JRE by putting the Java Server JRE (version 8u152) files in a C:\Program Files\Java\server-jre-8u152-windows-x64 folder and set the environment variables. Server JRE does not have an installer. Everything has been running without error for some time now.

I am tempted to make a deployment.security file with the suggested settings and put it on my *Production* server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source [Oracle technotes guides](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/properties.html)
The deploy.properties file should be located here:

> \LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties

More precisely:
For user jsmith

> C:\Users\jsmith\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties

Within that file is where there are a number of "deployment.security" prefixed settings you can change.

**Update** it appears this file is missing according to [Stig -
 Java runtime environment jre version 8 windows 2017-01-05 finding V-66943](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/java_runtime_environment_jre_version_8_windows/2017-01-05/finding/V-66943) - as per their document:

> Fix Text (F-73043r1_fix)
>   
>   Create the JRE deployment.properties file:
>   
>   No default file exists. A text file named deployment.properties, and the directory structure in which it is located must be manually created.
>   The location must be aligned as defined in the \Lib\deployment.config file.
>   
> C:\Windows\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties is an example.
>   
>   Now unfortunately `lib\deployment.config` does not exist but this might explain how to create it (though not sure it would be used or how to test if used)[stig - java runtime environment jre version 8 windows 2016-09-27 finding V-66941](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/java_runtime_environment_jre_version_8_windows/2016-09-27/finding/V-66941)

**Update and Bingo**

> By default no deployment.config file exists, so no system-wide deployment.properties file exists.
>   
>   As per [Oracles Technote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/properties.html)

It can however be created.  Looks like you just ned to put it in the proper location and make sure its used - you'll need to find a means of gtesting an entry before and after

Comment: I do not have a Java folder in my c:\users\jsmith\AppData\LocalLow\ directory. Users do not applications anyway. Apache Tomcat runs under the local system account.

Comment: It's the local users application settings, not necessarily the installed application itself.  As you can see in there, or a folder or two up you usually have other applications settings in there, for example chrome, firefox, etc.  Tomcat runs under the local system account - but you installed the Java Server JRE under your account correct?  Let me hunt around a bit more!

Comment: I downloaded it and its a zip with no installer - and no deployment.properties file... still googling...

Comment: That's the odd part: no installer because it's a portable program. :-) My checklist expects the file in the C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ folder.

Comment: It looks like based on this [Java runtime environment jre version 8 windows 2017-01-05 finding V-66943](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/java_runtime_environment_jre_version_8_windows/2017-01-05/finding/V-66943) that it might actually be a bug.  They say you can create the file but it'd take a bit of research to get the correct settings in there and verify they're being used.  I did download the java server 9 version, it's also missing - still looking for you but maybe its deprecated in some way?

Comment: Where is your checklist from, is it a public checklist that I could take a look at from a website and see if theres something newer for java server 8/9?  Do you usually use Java Server and not just the plain old JDk/JRE's - I ask as we have tons of Java servers, even some from other vendors - none run the "Java Server" JRE version and these servers handle half a thousand transactions per second

Comment: I use the DoD's STIG checklist for JRE; I assume I should not share it. I used the Server JRE instead of the plain old JRE because it lacks some browser and user client stuff that I do not need. That would make it easier to secure but perhaps not easier for the checklist. :-)

Comment: Just updated my answer 4 times :-/  Take a look if you havent.  If it helps, please feel free to mark it as answered.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I will add the files and test it.